# enforce arguments to a specific list of values

Tags: python, function

What is the pythonic way to enforce a function to take a specific set of values for a given parameter? For instance there is a function like:

```
def results(status, data):
```

I want to restrict the parameter `status` to a set of values like 0, 1 or 99.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to check the value inside the function:

```
def results(status, data):
    valid = {0, 1, 99}
    if status not in valid:
        raise ValueError("results: status must be one of %r." % valid)
```

Here, `valid` is a set, because the only thing we care about is whether `status` is a member of the collection (we aren't interested in order, for example). To avoid recreating the set each time you use the function, you'd probably define it as a "constant"<sup>1</sup> global:

```
VALID_STATUS = {0, 1, 99}

def results(status, data):
    if status not in VALID_STATUS:
        raise ValueError("results: status must be one of %r." % VALID_STATUS)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> results(7, [...])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in results
ValueError: results: status must be one of {0, 1, 99}.
```

Always try to raise [the most appropriate exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) you can - [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) tells the caller of the function what's going on better than [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Exception) does, for example.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's not *really* constant, but by convention, `ALL_UPPERCASE` variable names in Python are considered to be intended as constants.

Comment: Is there any pythonic way of doing it, as of 2023?

Comment: Yes: if it's necessary to check at all (e.g. for security reasons, if the function is receiving user-supplied input), check inside the function and react accordingly, as described in this answer. In general however it's unpythonic to check argument values at runtime as a matter of course. Searching "python consenting adults" may provide further illumination on this topic.

Answer (score 8):

You can check within the function itself if `status` is a valid value and if it is not then raise an exception.

```
def results(status,data):
    list_valid_status = [0, 1, 99]
    # list_valid_status = (0, 1, 99) # could be a tuple so it doesn't get modified by accident
    if status not in list_valid_status:
        raise ValueError("Wrong status")
```

Comment: Also, a set is `{0, 1, 99}` - `(0, 1, 99)` is a tuple (and the reason for using a set is that the `in` membership test is faster for a set, not that it doesn't get modified).

Answer (score 6):

An alternative option would be to go with Enums for instance

```
from enum import IntEnum

class STATUSES(IntEnum):
    ZERO = 0
    ONE = 1
    OTHER = 99

def results(status, data):
    status = STATUS(status)
```

calling `STATUS(status)` would raise `ValueError` similar to other answers, but with this approach you have some benefits:

1. Putting type annotation `status:STATUSES` would make it easier for others to get set of valid fields (especially when working with IDE)
2. You can name `STATUSES` in human-readable format (don't have a broader context of this particular use case)

Answer (score 3):

I put together a decorator `validateParameterList` that does this check for keyword arguments specifically. It checks for valid parameter options within a specified key-value mapping (`combinations`) and/or `names`-`options` pairs. The `required` field was added to make the optional parameters not-so-optional (maybe some won't like this so much...).

This particular decorator works with async functions. If async is not needed, remove `async` and `await` from the decorator.

**Decorator:**

```py
def validateParamList(
    combinations: Dict = {},
    names: List[str] = [],
    options: List[List[str]] = [[]],
    required: set = set(),
):
    def innerFunction(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def validateParamsWrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            allowables = {
                **combinations,
                **{key: val for (key, val) in zip(names, options)},
            }

            missing_required = required.difference(kwargs.keys())

            if len(missing_required) != 0:
                raise Exception(
                    f"Required keyword values: Keyword argument{'s' if len(missing_required) > 1 else ''} {missing_required} was not provided."
                )

            for key, vals in allowables.items():
                if key in kwargs.keys() and kwargs[key] not in vals:
                    arg_type = "required" if key in required else "optional"

                    raise ValueError(
                        f"Invalid {arg_type} keyword value: Valid values for'{key}' are {vals}. '{kwargs[key]}' was provided."
                    )

            return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return validateParamsWrapper

    return innerFunction
```

**Application:**

```py
@validateParamList(
    combinations={
        "var2": range(10),
        "var3": [True, False],
        "var4": ["ok_val_1", "ok_val_2", "ok_val_3", "ok_val_4"],
    },
    required={"var3", "var4"},
)
async def myFunc(
    self,
    var1: str = "unchecked_default",
    var2: int = -1,
    var3: bool = None,
    var4: str = "",
):
    pass
```

For this example:

- If `var2` is not provided on the `myFunc` call, there will be no ValueError and `var2` will be `-1`
- If `var3` or `var4` are not provded on the `myFunc` call, there will be an Exception
- If `va2`, `var3`, and `var4` are provided on the `myFunc` call and any is invalid, there will be a ValueError