# How can I accept only some strings in Python function?

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

I want to make it like this:

```
>>> myfunc("strawberry")
ok
# myfunc only works with strawberry
```

I know that most people will answer with:

```
def myfunc(something):
   if something == "strawberry":
      print("ok")
```

But I want to do all this in the parameter setting.
Like, kind of like this:

```
def myfunc(something: OnlyThese["strawberry", "cake"]:
   print("ok")
```

Although the code above is very incorrect, I want to see if Python already has a feature like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enforce arguments to a specific list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854380/enforce-arguments-to-a-specific-list-of-values)

Comment: If you use a type checker, [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) is the standard annotation for what you tried to do with `OnlyThese`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't believe there is a way to do what you are wanting to do without writing code in the function body.

I found answers to a similar question at

[enforce arguments to a specific list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854380/enforce-arguments-to-a-specific-list-of-values)